# distribution provisioning and code signing issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, provisioning

I just generated a ad hoc distribution provisioning. I dragged this into xcode and then set my ad hoc build to be iphone distribution. Followed every single step in this [tutorial](http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4). The issue is that when I follow this instruction to see my list of devices it doesn't even have a ProvisionedDevices key in the embedded.mobileprovison. The key goes something like this:

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>8CH38P5X6X.*</string>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>8CH38P5X6X.*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2012-03-17T00:31:45Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Fever</string> //this is not my app name, how come it's here
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>291</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>101F3A06-B33C-411A-8173-A4CEAFF5E673</string>
        <key>Version</key>
    <string>101F3A06-B33C-411A-8173-A4CEAFF5E673</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The weirdest issue is that it has an app name in the , which is not my app name!! How is this even possible? Something is messed up..

This 8CH38P5X6X is also the App ID of my other app called Fever... how.. how is this possible. I've code signed adhoc using iphone distribution and it clearly says this:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I removed/clear the provisioning profile that I have for the Fever app, restart xcode, and tried to build the archive again and it works! Anyone ever have issues with multiple provisioning profile on your xcode being mixed up like this?

Comment: Yup, deleting everything and starting from scratch is usually a good solution in these situations. Be sure to answer your question and accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having such issues, please delete all other distribution provisioning profile you have on your system.